# Using C# to access Query from TFS, but unable to access some fields from Query

Tags: c#, tfs

I am bringing in a query from TFS into an application I wrote in C#.  Everything is working fine except I cannot access certain fields from the query.  They don't show up.  I think perhaps they are most likely custom fields added to our project.  For example: The build version number...  In the TFS query, the field is called ObjectVersion.  But I cannot use it, it doesn't exist in my code.

This is what I have.  The TFSCheckIter() method just converts the iterationpath to something that my C# program recognizes, "TFSitemIteration".   The lines Commented out are the Fields that I cant access.

```
Uri collectionUri = new Uri("http://Server/tfs/DefaultCollection/");

NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password");
TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri, credential);
teamProjectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();

WorkItemStore workItemStore = teamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

var togProject = workItemStore.Projects.OfType<Project>().FirstOrDefault(project => project.Name == "ProjectName");
if (togProject != null)
{
    var CMRAQuery = togProject.StoredQueries.OfType<StoredQuery>().FirstOrDefault(query => query.Name == "TFSBuildTasks");
    if (CMRAQuery != null)
    {
        WorkItemCollection WrkItmLst = workItemStore.Query(CMRAQuery.QueryText.Replace("@project", "\"ProjectName\"").Replace("@me", "\"Name\""));

        foreach (WorkItem TFSitem in WrkItmLst)
        {
            TFSitemName = TFSitem.Title;
            //TFSitemVersion = TFSitem.ObjectVersion; 
            //TFSitemType = TFSitem.ObjectType;
            TFSitemState = TFSitem.State;
            TFSitemIterPath = TFSitem.IterationPath;
            //TFSitemconfig = TFSitem.IncludeConfig;
            //TFSitemLB = TFSitem.LoadBalancer;
            //TFSitemFW = TFSitem.Framework;

            TFSCheckIter();

            if (TFSitemState == "D-Promote" | TFSitemState == "I-Promote")
            {
                 label5.Text = TFSitemName;
                 label6.Text = TFSitemState;
                 label7.Text = TFSitemIteration;
                 label8.Text = TFSitemVersion;
            }
    }

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Fields property `TFSitemVersion = TFSitem.Fields['ObjectVersion'].Value`. I suggest to use the Reference Name, e.g. `YourCompany.ObjectVersion`.